# Adminer Tables-Filter plugin with Pematon / adminer-custom

Tags: php, plugins, adminer

I want to use the tables-filter plugin with the pematon/adminer-custom package.

Tables-filter works fine with a plain adminer.

Problem: In pematon/adminer-custom Tables-filter doesn't show on the screen.

I have been looking through the source code trying to find what may be excluding it or hiding it. I can't find what is preventing it from showing.

Can anyone suggest how I might enable the tables-filter in pematon/adminer-custom?

---

#### Pics and references.

[adminer-custom](https://github.com/pematon/adminer-custom)

[adminer original](https://www.adminer.org/en/)

[tables-filter plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/plugins/tables-filter.php)

[git repo of my adminer-custom with the tables-filter enabled](https://github.com/dgleba/adminer-custom-pem2)

---

tables-filter SHOWING in adminer original

[image: table-filter showing in adminer original]

---

tables-filter NOT SHOWING in pematon adminer-custom

[image: tables-filter not showing in pematon adminer-custom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both AdminerSimpleMenu and AdminerTablesFilter define method tablesPrint. The first plugin wins and the method from the second plugin is not called at all. So, the only solution right now is to disable AdminerSimpleMenu. Just delete it from your index.php.